# ¿Cuál es el uso de la palabra clave _Generic introducida en C11?

Tags: c

He leído el estándar C11 y el mismo contiene
una característica interesante del lenguaje C y es el uso de `_Generic`...

Por su contexto me imagino que sirve para hacer expresiones genéricas en el lenguaje, pero no termino de 
entenderla.

Este es el código que he probado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ObtenerTipo(x)                   \
          _Generic((x),                  \
   char      : "char",                   \
   short     : "short",                  \
   int       : "int",                    \
   long      : "long",                   \
   long long : "long long",              \
   default   : "desconocido"             \
)

int main(void) {
  return printf("Tipo: %s\n", ObtenerTipo(0xDEADBEEF0);
}
```

Lo que arroja en mi ordenador es:

```
long
```

¿Cómo funciona `_Generic` en el lenguaje C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Introducción

`_Generic` es una nueva palabra clave del lenguaje C, introducida en su último estándar [(C11)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) cuyo objetivo es dar un comportamiento en base al tipo de dato que guarda la expresión que evalúa:

```
_Generic(ArgumentoExpresion,   \
         <Tipo>: <Expresión1>, \
        [<Tipo>: <ExpresiónN>, \]
)
```

<sub>Nótese que los corchetes (`[]`) significan que puede haber más de uno, ver ejemplo abajo.</sub>

#### Ejemplo:

Su comportamiento es similar al de un `switch`, la principal diferencia es que `_Generic` evalua los tipos, tomemos como ejemplo la macro que has puesto anteriormente:

```
#define ObtenerTipo(x)                   \
          _Generic((x),                  \
   char      : "char",                   \
   short     : "short",                  \
   int       : "int",                    \
   long      : "long",                   \
   long long : "long long",              \
   default   : "desconocido"             \
)
```

`_Generic` se encarga de *ubicar* el tipo de dato que reside en `(x)`, por lo que si es una operación, probablemente se sustituya por el caso `default` o genere errores en el código final, es decir que si escribimos la siguiente expresión:

```
ObtenerTipo(0xDEADBEEF0 + 1)
```

Saltará directamente a `default`, esto es porque `_Generic` no evalua expresiones, sólo los tipos del primer argumento pasado y posteriormente removerá la llamada para cambiarlo por su valor:

```
ObtenerTipo(0xDEADBEEF0)
```

Será sustituido por `int` o `long`, quizá `long long` en cualquiera de los casos, esto depende de la arquitectura de tu ordenador.

#### Limitaciones, o más bien, ¿Inconvenientes?

Como toda buena práctica y aplicación de una característica del lenguaje, sabemos que no es bueno abusar de ellas, por 'X' o 'Y' razón, `_Generic` no es la excepción.

1. Sólo se puede utilizar 1 argumento para evaluar el tipo.
2. Algúnos tipos como `char` o `short` son automáticamente evaluados a `int`
3. `_Generic("hola", ...)` será evaluado a `char *`.
4. `_Generic(+0.00, ...)` será evaluado a `double` directamente.
5. Esta característica se llama explícitamente `_Generic` *(No realmente limitación/inconveniente, pero los puristas se acostumbran rápido)*.
6. Entre otras.

Las principales limitaciones de la palabra clave `_Generic` es en base a los tipos, sin embargo, es totalmente aplicable a cualquier tipo, de hecho, la mayoría de estas *limitaciones* pueden ser facilmente trabajadas haciendo *cast* al operando pasado como argumento.

#### Casos de uso

En practicamente todo lenguaje existen los objetos genéricos, sin embargo, el lenguaje C no es tan agraciado, pero nos han bendecido con `_Generic` para darle un poco más de *sazón* y es poder ejecutar diversas funciones en base al tipo de dato del argumento pasado a la función, vease el caso de `tgmath.h`:

Imaginemos que tenemos la siguiente función:

```
int paddi(int a);
long paddl(long a);
long long paddll(long long a);
```

Es realmente tedioso tener que saber cual función llamar en un determinado caso, bueno, la macro lo resuelve de esta manera:

```
#define padd(a)             \
   _Generic((a),            \
      int      : paddi(a),  \
      long     : paddl(a),  \
      long long: paddll(a)  \
)
```

Y asi solo hay que llamar a la macro:

```
padd(10); /* Listo!!! */
padd(0x1234567890AB);
```

#### En resumen...

La palabra clave `_Generic` tiene bastantes usos y es una de las mejores funcionalidades introducidas en el estándar C11 del lenguaje, definitivamente ayuda a que el código sea más legible y permite la facilidad entre varios tipos, pero como toda característica de un lenguaje, no es bueno abusar de ella.

Saludos :)

Comment: Excelente iniciativa para tener documentación en español +1

Comment: ¡Gracias! A decir verdad, no entendí el uso de `_Generic` hasta que escribí esta respuesta, tuve que realizar muchas pruebas antes de escribir eso ahí :P

Comment: @NaCl Eso es lo mejor de responder en SOes: te obligas a aprender y dominar conceptos para poder explicarlos a otros.

Comment: No es necesario que en cada alternativa se haga esto: `int: paddi(a)`. Es decir, los parámetros se pueden omitir (en este caso si).

Comment: Ej: `#define padd(a) _Generic((a), int:paddi, long:paddl,long long:paddll)(a)`

Comment: Y listo, al final del `_Generic` especificamos la cantidad de parámetros, que corresponde a cada función.

Comment: @MrDave1999 Claro! Considera agregar una nueva respuesta con ejemplos distintos al mío para mostrar las distintas formas en la que puedes hacerlo.